# Ajax Update Panel - What am I missing?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Problem: When suburb drop down list value is changed - Page is posting back.

Desired result: Changing value in drop down list updates post code text box value without a page post back (post code text box is normally hidden)

Page code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Suburb" runat="server" DataTextField="LocalityPhrase" 
      DataValueField="Locality"  AutoPostBack="true"  class="DropDown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Suburb_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanelPostCode" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="Postcode" runat="server" Visible="true"/>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Suburb" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub Suburb_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Suburb.SelectedIndexChanged
        'get postcode from suburb drop down
        Dim pCode As String = ""
        If Suburb.SelectedValue <> "" Then
            pCode = Suburb.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(Len(Suburb.SelectedItem.Text) - 5, 4)
        End If
        Postcode.Text = pCode
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears there was something wrong with my install of the AJAX toolkit. Removed and reloaded it in Visual Studio (2008) and all is well.